# Using cached canvas with React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am using an in-memory cache of canvas elements that were already partially drawn. I do it for performance and smooth user experience (no flickering). I need to remove the current canvas from its parent container div and append another one - upon certain triggers. I also need to draw on the current canvas and before it's removed - store it back in cache.

The non-react way, that works, is to render the component only once and then work heavily with Refs. Otherwise - every render overrides the current canvas and I need to append it again.

Question is - am I missing an obvious way of doing it properly - i.e. event->state update->render? Is there a way to make the render method use an existing DOM element? Or must I render and then manipulate directly?

Comment: Someone else might be able to suggest something specific, but this seems the ideal usecase for refs. I don't think you're missing anything at all here. From your description, you _really_ don't want it to do event->state update->render, because it's going to blow everything away. You want the canvas[es] all avalable all the time, to be mutable and outside the normal React [re]rendering cycle, otherwise performance will be awful